# Migrated to a WCF service with SOAP and JSON endpoint - JSON response not as expected

Tags: json, wcf, soap

I migrated a web service to a WCF service. The service exposes two endpoints, one returns JSON and one returns SOAP.

The SOAP endpoint works as expected, but the response from the JSON endpoint is wrapped with the response object name - something that did not exist in the JSON response the web service I migrated from used to return.

I tried working with the `BodyStyle` property, but all I got is an exception: `The body style 'Bare' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'`.

All my methods accept only POST requests.

This is how my service is configured:

```
<services>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://MyService.org/" contract="IMyService"/>
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="JsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" />
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonEndpointBehavior">
            <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```